# If $f(u_n)$ is bounded, why it is true that $(u_n)_n$ is bounded in $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, upper-lower-bounds

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded domain in $\mathbb{R^N}$, $p\geq 1$ and $(u_n)_n\subset W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$. I would like to show that $(u_n)_n$ is bounded in $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ and the only thing I know is that
$$\| u_n\|_{W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)} +\int_{\Omega} f(u_n) dx = c + o(\| u_n\|_{W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)} +1),$$
where $c$ is a positive constant and $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function.

It is written on my notes that in order to show $(u_n)_n$ is bounded in $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ it is enough to prove that the function $f$ is bounded.

I am trying, but I am not able to understand why this late statement is true, I mean, why it is enough just to show that $f$ is bounded? In addition, bounded from above and\or from below?

Could anyone please help or give some hints?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dividing the equation
$$\| u_n\|_{W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)} +\int_{\Omega} f(u_n) dx = c + o(\| u_n\|_{W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)} +1)$$
by $\| u_n\|_{W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)} +1$, we find that
$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} \left[\frac{\| u_n\|_{W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)}}{\| u_{n}\|_{W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)}+1} + \frac{1}{\| u_{n}\|_{W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)}+1}\int_{\Omega}f(u_n)~dx\right]  = \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{c}{\| u_{n}\|_{W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)}+1}.$$
Now suppose that there is a subsequence, again denoted by $u_n$, such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \| u_n\|_{W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)} = \infty.$ Then, as $f$ is bounded we have
$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} \left[  \frac{1}{\| u_{n}\|_{W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)}+1}\int_{\Omega}f(u_n)~dx\right] \leq \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{\|f\|_{\infty}|\Omega|}{\| u_{n}\|_{W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)}+1} = 0. $$
We clearly also have
$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{c}{\| u_{n}\|_{W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)}+1} = 0,$$
and as
$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{\| u_n\|_{W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)}}{\| u_{n}\|_{W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)}+1} = 1, $$
we reach the contradiction $1 = 0$. It follows that there is no subsequence of $(u_n)_{n \geq 1}$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \| u_n\|_{W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)} = \infty$, hence $(u_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is bounded in $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$.

Comment: I refer to the limsup involving the term $\int_{\Omega} f(u_n) dx$. I agree with your estimate, but if you are not sure that the integral is positive, could you say that also $$\limsup_n \left(\frac{\int_{\Omega} f(u_n) dx}{\| u_n\|_{W_0^{1,p}}+1}\right)=0?$$